# Is it possible to use the MMM tool without virtual IP capability?

Tags: networking, mysql, mysql-replication

We are on a host (Serverbeach) that does not support Virtual/floating IPs until you reserve at least a half-rack, which is just a little more than we are willing to spend per month right now. We do have 2 machines in one of their datacenters, and I am using these 2 machines right now in the Master-Master in Active-Passive Mode just like done by MMM -- http://mysql-mmm.org/. I have just set them up and I managing them manually, with manual switch on the Web frontend to tell it to connect to the correct (active) master.

Is there any way to use MMM without virtual IPs? Any other comments on this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible if you're willing to customise MMM a bit. We have part of a patch developed, but we never got around to finishing it. You're welcome to contact us and see if we can make some arrangements to get it finished.

Walter
Engineer @ Open Query

Comment: Just to use my rep to promote this, but Open Query are certainly the people to talk to about this.

Comment: Walter, that sounds great. Sorry, I was confused -- "Walter Engineer @ Open Query", is that your e-mail in some obfuscated anti-spam format? Or where can I contact you?